# New user creation notification mails are not going in Alfresco

Tags: java, share, alfresco, alfresco-share

When Admin creates a new user account, an email should go to the created user's mail id.
How can I enable this? Can I do it in "alfresco-global.properties", If yes, how?

Comment: Are other outbound emails from Alfresco already setup and working? (That'll be your first step)

Comment: Yes, I have done that. Mails are getting while Inviting members to a site by giving "notification.email.siteinvite=true". Is there any property to get mails while new user creation? Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible out of the box. You could however implement this functionality with a java behavior. Be sure to not interfere with the emails that is sent out when inviting external users though otherwise those will get double emails.

Update after doing some research:

Well, someone made a decision to not make the notification option configurable in the create user gui. I have followed the calls made from the GUI down to the repository and it ends up calling a java method documented like this:

`/**
     * Create a Person with an optionally generated user name. 
     * This version doesn't notify them.
     * 
 */`

Which means you have to do some coding to implement notifications in this scenario.

Comment: Thanx for your reply.
Emails are going for New Account creation if the admin is creating users by uploading .CSV file. Sending mails while creating new account is very common in all web sites, so I think Alfresco would have done it already.

Comment: I also think it would be nice if you could tick a box or something saying "notify user". I would log this as a change request in the Alfresco Jira (http://issues.alfresco.com)